# C# code works from Console function but does not work in SQL CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sqlclr

PLEASE HELP!!! I have a code to get data from AD. This used to work in SQL2014/Visual Studio2013. Now, we are migrating to SQL2016. I tested the code in a Console App and it worked just fine. It just does not work when I create the same code into a SQL CLR Stored Proc using Visual Studio 2017.

This is the code in the Console App:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection;
            DirectorySearcher search;
            SearchResult result;
            DirectoryEntry ldapconnection = null;
            string szJDEID = "";
            string szErrorMessage = "";
            string szNetworkID = "xyz";

            //--- Create and return new LDAP connection with desired settings  
            ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC.company.com:389", "userid", "password");
            ldapConnection.Path = "LDAP://DC=company,DC=com";
            ldapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;


            //--- create search object which operates on ldap connection object and set search object to only find the user specified  
            search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapconnection);
            search.Filter = "(&(samaccountname=" + szNetworkID.Trim() + ")(memberOf=CN=JDEdwards Users,OU=Mail Enabled Manual,OU=Groups,OU=Global,DC=company,DC=com))";

            result = search.FindOne();

            if (result != null)
            {
                //--- create an array of properties that we would like and add them to the search object  
                string[] requiredproperties = new string[] { "extensionattribute13" };

                foreach (string property in requiredproperties)
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);

                result = search.FindOne();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (string property in requiredproperties)
                        foreach (object mycollection in result.Properties[property])
                            szJDEID = mycollection.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                szErrorMessage = "ERROR: This user does not belong to the JDEdwards Users AD Group. Please check with the IT Helpdesk team.";
            }
        }
```

I get the value of szJDEID as stored in Extension Attribute13. When I put the same code in a SQL CLR Stored Proc, the Logic always returns the szErrorMessage value.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]

Comment: also double check your target .netframework, and verify if it its supported in SQL2016

Comment: Hi Clint:

I already have this in my CLR function.

public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ValidateAD(string szNetworkID, out string szJDEID, out string szErrorMessage)

Also, I changed the target .net framework from 4 to 4.5 to 4.7...in spite of all these, the stored proc is not working.

what else can I look for?

Comment: you said the very same code worked in SQL2014, right ?

Comment: the same code worked perfectly in SQL2014..that is correct

Comment: then check, the .netframework version in your new SQL2016 and see if your code targets that

Comment: how do I do that? please help by telling me the exact steps..

Comment: You have migrated to a new server Windows2016 or did you install SQL2016 on the same server as SQL2014 ?

Comment: it is a brand new server

Comment: Windows Server 2016 and you have SQL2016 installed in it, is that what you mean

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: how do I chat there? sorry 1st time...I can't find a box to type in my reply

Comment: do you see join chat room, something like that ?

Comment: at the bottom of that room, it says "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207872/discussion-between-clint-and-vram).

Comment: Any break-throughs ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally. As you had rightly pointed earlier, the bindDn was incorrect. The issue is we moved from one DC to another. I used lip.exe to find out the principal - userid@domain.com. Also, the ldapConnection.Path was not needed anymore as it was incorrect with the new DC. So, finally, it is working. Thanks Clint.